# How to find average of sales quantity based on last 7 days in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image][image][image]

I want to find the average sales quantity of last 7 days for 3 conditions i) first floor and row_no =1 , ii)  first floor and row_no =2 , iii)  second*emphasized text* floor and row_no =1

```
select sum((sales_qty)/7) from testing WHERE entry_date  between  current_date  - interval '7 days' and current_date  at time zone 'UTC' and location and row_no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `conditional aggregation` as follows:

```
Select sum(case when rowno = 1 and location = 'first floor' 
         then sales_qty else 0 end)/7 as firstfloor_rowno1,
       sum(case when rowno = 2 and location = 'first floor' 
         then sales_qty else 0 end)/7 as firstfloor_rowno2,
       sum(case when rowno = 1 and location = 'second floor' 
         then sales_qty else 0 end)/7 as secondfloor_rowno1
  From testing 
 WHERE entry_date  between current_date interval '7 days' and current_date
```

Comment: could you please give me a full query starting from select please

Comment: i am a fresher thats why i m asking

Comment: Please make sure that you have data available which satisfy the where condition.

Comment: please see again above i have followed the way you instruct me

Comment: It may happen if there is leading or trailing space in the location. Use trim on location and try

Comment: but still it doesnt work for me (average is not calculated)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, it is best to use `filter` for conditional aggregation.  I also doubt that you have future entry dates, so I would recommend:

```
select sum(sales_qty) filter (where rowno = 1 and location = 'first floor') / 7 as firstfloor_rowno1,
       sum(sales_qty) filter (where rowno = 2 and location = 'first floor') / 7 as firstfloor_rowno2,
       sum(sales_qty) filter (where rowno = 1 and location = 'second floor') / 7 as secondfloor_rowno1
from testing 
where entry_date >= current_date interval '6 days'
```

Note that this includes the *current date*, which is the 7th day.  If you want data on the preceding 7 days, then use:

```
where entry_date >= current_date interval '7 days' and
      entry_date < current_date
```

Using `between` is incorrect because it would include records at midnight of the current date -- and that is not your intention.